# Google Apps Scriplet is not run when returning HTML

Tags: html, google-apps-script, scriptlet

I have a very simple web app with the code:

```
function doGet() {
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>The time is &lt;?= new Date() ?&gt;</b>');
}
```

But the new Date() isn not run. The whole is rendered as text:

The time is

Answer (score 0):

When I construct the text and the date value before using it is rendered correctly.

Here is how I made it:

```
 function doGet() {
  var date=new Date();
  var html= '<b>The Time is:'+' '+date+' '+'</b>';
  return HtmlService 
     .createHtmlOutput(html);
  }
```

If any one knows a simpler way, appreciate the answer.